# Laravel: How does Controller access parameters from Route?

Tags: php, laravel

I am very obviously a noob to Laravel and hope that someone can help me out.

The about screen is accessed through the route

```
 Route::get('/about', array('as' => 'about', function()
 {
    return View::make('about')->with('title','About Screen')->with('class','about');
 }));
```

The variables $title and $class are accessible in about.blade.php by {{ $title }} and {{ $class }}.  If instead, I have a Controller in between,

```
 Route::get('hello/create', array('as' => 'create', 'uses' => 
 'HelloController@create', function()
 {
    return View::make('hello/create')->with('title','Create')->with('class','hello.create');
 }));
```

How do I access $title and $class in the HelloController.php code (so that I can propagate the values to the coming View)?

P.S. I do know about the /hello/create/{name of variable} which is the answer on nearly all questions similar to this, but don't know how to use it to transmit variables NOT keyed onto the Http Request.

Comment: The only way to pass values in a GET route to the controller is to indicate it in the route. As explained in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters

Comment: If you really want to pass extra data to the route->controller, you could disguise the link as a form and create a POST request. That's easy to do with bootstrap but it's **not** SEO friendly. You have to put that into account.

Comment: Thanks for replying Dmitri.  I kind of suspected what you are saying but hoped that that would not be the case. What do you mean by "put that into account" please?

Comment: It means that search robots don't follow POST 'links', only GET links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$title` and `$class` are the values you are manually giving to the blade. These aren't the values that you are receiving in GET parameters in your route. So, you would do it the same way as you did in the closure.

**Your route:**

```
Route::get('hello/create', array('as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'HelloController@create'));
```

**Controller method:**

```
class HelloController{
 public function create(){
  return View::make('hello/create')->with('title','Create')->with('class','hello.create');
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

From what I understood, you can also call controller's method inside the route's closure and pass parameters to the controller and call the view with these values inside the controller's method.

**Your route file:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HelloController;

Route::get('hello/create',function(){
    $hello_obj = new HelloController();
    return $hello_obj->create('create','hello.create');
});
```

**Controller method:**

```
class HelloController{
 public function create($title,$class){
  return View::make('hello/create')->with('title',$title)->with('class',$class);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is from the Controller to the View hello.create which I have already done.  My question is to use something like $title and $class in place of 'Create' and 'hello.create' in your HelloController class..

Comment: @DanielWong you could declare them as variables. `$title = 'Create'` and `$class = 'hello.create'` and pass them as `with('title',$title)->with('class',$class);`

Comment: Yes I have already tried that successfully.  But I want to do the assignment at the Route, not inside the Controller.

Comment: @DanielWong Your statement is highly confusing. You want to assign those at the route. You don't want to use GET parameters. You want to pass those variables from the route to the controller method(what difference would it make if you directly use them in the method anyway?).

Comment: Hi Vivek, the Routes that call the blade views directly pass parameters directly from the Route file. As a noob, I thought that I could do the same for Route files that fed a Controller before the blade views.

Comment: @DanielWong You could that too. I have updated my answer to show how. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again Vivek. The updated Route does not mention $title and $class but these are used in the Controller.I haven't tried instantiating a new Controller object but $title and $class are undefined in the Controller.

Comment: @DanielWong Notice the parameters in `create()` method as well.

Comment: Thanks that worked!  This is the first time this question has been answered this way.  Thanks again.

Comment: @DanielWong Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to clear your flow. You are -at the moment- manually setting the variables to be returnet to the view, so your route should look like this:

```php
Route::get('hello/create', 'HelloController@create');
```

Then, your controller handles the logic:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return view('hello.create')->with('title','Create')->with('class','hello.create');
}
```

---

Now, if you need to send parameters from your frontend to your controller, you have two options:

1. Define [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters).
2. Use query params.

### Option 1

For the first option, you'll need to define your required/optional parameters in the route itselft:

```php
Route::get('hello/create/{a_variable}', 'HelloController@create');
```

Then you access this parameter in any of this ways:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return view('hello.create')->with('a_variable', $request->a_variable);
}
```

or injecting the variable in the method:

```php
public function create(Request $request, $a_variable)
{
    return view('hello.create')->with('a_variable', $a_variable);
}
```

### Option 2

For the use of query params, you should include this options when making the request. If your route looks like this:

```php
Route::get('hello/create', 'HelloController@create');
```

You could specify query params like this:

```php
GET www.my-domain.com/hello/create?first_parameter=value_1&second_parameter=value_2
```

So in your controller you access this values like this:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $value_1 = $request->get('first_parameter');
    $value_2 = $request->get('second_parameter');

    return view('hello.create')
               ->with('value_1', $value_1)
               ->with('value_2', $value_2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can't use the {a_variable} method because the value of a_variable is assigned in the Route statement i.e. return View::make('about')->with('title','About Screen')->with('class','about');

Comment: What is the 2nd option please?

Comment: No. What you are doing in your route is called a Closure function. It is an annonymous function that performs an action, moving this logic inside a Controller method should work the same way. As I said, the below options is when you are including the parameter when making the request (with Axios or from your blade view).

Comment: Understood and agree, but that sounds ... messy.  Add parameters to the Route only when the View file is called next.  Otherwise add them in the Controller file.  And as a noob, I would not assume that to be the case without the benefit of more experienced minds.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielWong in reality is the opposite: you should always decouple your code a single action to each class. So, your `route` should define the endpoint and delegate a controller method to handle the call. Then, your controller should call your repositories/helpers to handle the request and return a view/json.

Comment: @DanielWong regarding the parameters part: I put the above options WHEN you need to send parameter/variable to the backend. For example, when doing a search (`GET` request), you need to send the query that the user made. Or when sending data with a form (`POST` request). In the case you specified there is no need to send data from the view to the backend because your are setting manually the variables to be returned to the view (check the first part of my answer). Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You are alreading sending data to view using with().
Echo it in your view file using $variablename set in with() Example: `<?php echo $title; ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  No.  I can't echo $title in the view file without assigning it in the Controller file.

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: I am using revision 5.4.